# How do I make PyCharm understand that certain files/directories are excluded from coverage?

Tags: pycharm, coverage.py, pytest-cov

How do I make PyCharm understand that certain files/directories are excluded from coverage, because right now it shows me "0% files, not covered" for directories like venv and tests.

Alt+Shift+F6, I select the .coverage file that only reports on files from the src/ directory, yet PyCharm shows me coverage for other files and directories as well. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. One needs to go to `Settings -> Project: ... -> Project Structure`, and set it up like this:

[image]

Comment: Excluding directories also has (in many cases undesired) side effects such as not being listed in search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .coveragerc file that configures coverage.  To omit the venv directory:

```
[run]
omit = venv
```

I would recommend that you *not* exclude tests from coverage.  They are your code, and you want to learn about them.  Coverage can tell you things like shadowed tests, or unused helper code.

Comment: Tried this already, doesn't work.

Here's what I'm seeing in the project tab, in PyCharm: https://imgur.com/a/p8Llpa0
Also my .coverage file isn't even covering the directories that I'm being shown there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what PyCharm is showing you there.